# Module vs. Controller

Tags: php, model-view-controller, routes, module

I'm writing the bits and pieces for a (*oh no, another*) PHP framework, as a learning experience, and hopefully for future use on smaller projects.

I've done a fair bit of reading, namely the Reference Docs of existing frameworks. I see the word *Module* thrown around alot, and from my reading and previous experience, a Module is a concept applied to divide related code (Views, Controllers, Models, etc.)

**I'm curious, how does SO see a *Module* in this context? (context being MVC web application architecture, or similar application development pattern)**

I'm trying to determine how best to apply this, as (I believe) it fits my current predicament. For a music website a module would be seen as an `Artist`, `Producer`, etc., whereas the Controllers would be `Profile`, `Media`, etc. This leaves actions of course, such as `View`, or `Edit`.

This all seems good, because now I can do routing like so:

```
'Artist/Profile/View/{ALIAS}'
    +- Module : Artist
    +- Controller : Profile
    +- Action : View

//this may be accessed via music.com/artist/{alias}
//defaulting the Controller and Action
```

..but I'm trying to figure out how the *Module* concept fits here, specifically, how I would organize or modify my Controllers to accommodate.

---

This is the sort of file system layout I'm thinking of;

```
+- Root
    +- 'index.php'
    +- 'api.php'
    +- Modules
    |   +- Public
    |   |   +- Controllers
    |   |   +- Views
    |   |
    |   +- User
    |   |   +- Controllers
    |   |   +- Views
    |   |
    |   +- Artist
    |   |   +- Controllers
    |   |   +- Views
    |   |
    |   +- Producer
    |   |   +- Controllers
    |   |   +- Views
    |   |
    |   +- Venue
    |   |   +- Controllers
    |   |   +- Views
    |   |
    |   +- Administrator
    |       +- Controllers
    |       +- Views
    |
    +- Models
    +- Config
    +- ...
```

Comment: Some people will discourage you because you are reinventing the wheel, but i highly encourage you. If we will never open the toy how will we know that "How It Works"? Next step is to make your own version of toy. Good Luck Bro.

Comment: **Thanks Imran Naqvi**; I've seen much discouragement around SO and elsewhere, especially with regards to "reinventing frameworks", and while some criticism seems at times applicable, I'd never understand half of what I understand now, had I not reinvented all the things I've reinvented :) I don't see reason in much of the negative feedback though. What are people worried about, too many frameworks? I think high efficiency production systems should be trusted to high efficiency production frameworks, but that's no excuse to step on someone's learning. It's refreshing to see encouragement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modules (called Plugins in CakePHP) are pretty much mini apps in most frameworks. They have their own MVC structure inside them and are usually self contained, maybe only relying on the main apps models to keep the code reusable.

We use Zend where we work, and examples of modules would be the

1. Admin module for administrators of the site to do changes to the system.
2. Web module for the general front end of the site
3. User module for the logged in users who have additional management tools to carry out their activities on the site

Basically all of them fall under the same site/system, but deal in mostly non overlapping ways.

Comment: **Thanks JohnP;** This appears to be similar to my understanding, however, I'm trying to bridge the logic gap in applying it to my design. It makes sense (like in the Zend example) that different tools are available depending on the active Module. Keeping the Model separate from the Module stacks seems like a good practice here, to permit system wide access to the datasource, no?

Comment: Yup. We usually access the models from the main project. We also keep a few things in a separate library folder  with the same hierarchy as Zend so as to keep thing central.

Comment: Excellent, thanks **JohnP**; I'll likely accept your answer, however I'm going to let the question sit for a few in the hopes that others will contribute/expand. Please feel free to share any other information you feel pertinent here; I'll be reading up on the Zend Framework more thoroughly.

Comment: cool. You could also read up on HMVC. Codeigniter has an excellent HMVC plugin that I used which lets you plug in and remove modules to your project effortlessly. Makes things very modular : http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/hvmc-an-introduction-and-application/

Answer (score 1):

In the simplest case, a module will be a folder in you app (preferably in a pre-determined location, like `/modules`). You will then have a whole MVC stack inside each module, with shared libraries and the framework itself being on the top level.

Comment: **Thanks abesto;** JohnP's answer and yours expand on one another it seems. Creating new MVC stacks for each Module makes sense, however (correct me if you feel differently) as I previously commented, exclusion of the Model seems like a better practice here, to ensure system wide accessibility. I'm implementing an Model/Method driven ACL checkpoint, so regardless of the Module->Controller talking to the Model, only permitted sessions will get any feedback.

Comment: That's a decision that should be answered on a per-project basis. For example on my current project different modules can be on different servers, communicating with each other via JSON-RPC. In this case it's an obvious choice to place models at the module level. Your reasoning is just as correct.